# How To View Documents Uploaded Through Custom Profile

Tags: custom-fields, profile, contact-view

I created a custom profile field which has an upload field to allow users uploaded scanned documents as part of their contact records so that when viewing the user's Civicrm Contact record i can view the uploaded document. 
However I find that when viewing the contact record i cannot see the uploaded documents. Only the upload field is visible.

Does anyone know how this can be implemented in CiviCRM or am doing something wrong? I am using CiviCRM 4.6.15 with wordpress.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

we did have some issue with uploading files to custom field since 4.6.5 and above

I did made a quick test against http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org which is running on civicrm version 4.6.18

And the issue got fixed so please try to upgrade to the latest version and then please test the same

thanks

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. My problem with using the latest version of Civi is because i wont be able to use Clickatell SMS Gateway again.